# Index match with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs

df1

```
 Len    Bar
 x      a
 y      a
 z      a
 x      b
 y      b
 z      b
 x      c
 y      c
 z      c
```

df2

```
Len/Bar a   b   c
x       4   2   8
y       2   7   7
z       6   3   9
```

Need output to be

```
Len Bar Amount
x   a   4
y   a   2
z   a   6
x   b   2
y   b   7
z   b   3
x   c   8
y   c   7
z   c   9
```

In excel I use index match formula `=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(A19,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B19,$B$1:$D$1,0))`

But is there any way to do the same using map or merge

Comment: Try `df2.set_index('Len/Bar').unstack()`?

Comment: how does df1 enter into this picture?

Comment: What is connection between `df1` and `df2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first reshape `df2` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join with `df1`:

```
df2 =df2.set_index('Len/Bar').unstack().rename_axis(('Bar','Len')).reset_index(name='Amount')
df2 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Len', 'Bar'])
print (df2)
  Len Bar  Amount
0   x   a       4
1   y   a       2
2   z   a       6
3   x   b       2
4   y   b       7
5   z   b       3
6   x   c       8
7   y   c       7
8   z   c       9
```

Another solution:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Len/Bar').stack().rename_axis(('Bar','Len')).rename('Amount')
df2 = df1.join(df2, on=['Len', 'Bar'])
print (df2)
  Len Bar  Amount
0   x   a       4
1   y   a       2
2   z   a       6
3   x   b       2
4   y   b       7
5   z   b       3
6   x   c       8
7   y   c       7
8   z   c       9
```

EDIT:

If you dont know if need merge/join it depends if need filter reshaped `df2` by `df1` or not.

See difference:

```
#removed some rows
print (df1)
  Len Bar
0   x   a
1   y   a
2   z   a
3   x   b
4   y   b
```

---

```
print (df2)
  Bar Len  Amount
0   a   x       4
1   a   y       2
2   a   z       6
3   b   x       2
4   b   y       7
5   b   z       3
6   c   x       8
7   c   y       7
8   c   z       9
```

And after `merge` rows are filtered by columns `Len` and `Bar` from `df1`:

```
print (df3)
  Len Bar  Amount
0   x   a       4
1   y   a       2
2   z   a       6
3   x   b       2
4   y   b       7
```

Answer (score 3):

Incidentally, you do not seem to need `df1` at all:

```
df3 = df2.set_index('Len/Bar').stack().reset_index()
df3.columns = "Len", "Bar", "Amount"
#  Len Bar Amount
#0   x   a      4
#1   x   b      2
#2   x   c      8
#3   y   a      2
#4   y   b      7
#5   y   c      7
#6   z   a      6
#7   z   b      3
#8   z   c      9
```

Unless you want to borrow the column names from it:

```
df3.columns = df1.columns + ("Amount",)
```